# Running basic PowerShell commands in C# error cmdlet not found

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a C# console program, and I want to run PowerShell commands NOT SCRIPTS, but no matter what command I try to run in the PowerShell runspace, it gets an error saying cmdlet not found. It can be as simple as the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            ps.AddCommand("(Get-Date).AddDays(1)");
            var result = ps.Invoke();

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I can type this command at the PowerShell command line and it runs perfectly fine. I don't have to add any modules to run it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A command would be `Get-Date` alone. When you use AddCommand that's what it expects. For example,

```
ps.AddCommand("Get-Date").AddParameter("Format", "u").Invoke();
```

See *[AddCommand(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182430(v=vs.85).aspx)*

You have a script it, and it doesn't easily fit into AddCommand (because it isn't one). Tty AddScript instead:

```
ps.AddScript("(Get-Date).AddDays(1)").Invoke();
```

Comment: What if I wanted to store that result in a variable?

Comment: As in store it in your class? You can still assign the return from Invoke() as you've done in your original, I just simplified it a bit for the sake of the example.